# append time values in bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I couldn't find what I am doing wrong in this script,
I want the variable TimeVec to have all three time values.
The script is supposed to save multiple running times of a program

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEFORMAT=%R
TimeVec=""
for run in 1 2 3; do(
    exec 3>&1 4>&2
    foo=$( { time sleep 1 1>&3 2>&4; }  2>&1 )
    exec 3>&- 4>&-
    TimeVec+=$foo
    echo $TimeVec
)
done
echo $TimeVec
```

this is what I get

```
1.001
1.003
1.003
```

EDIT

i would like the TimeVec variable to store all three time values.

Comment: What's the script supposed to do? and what are the three items you mean in your output?

Comment: The script is supposed to save multiple running times of a program. i would like the TimeVec variable to store all three time values.

Comment: What about storing values in an array?  Note that putting stuff into `( ... )` creates a subshell that isolates variables. Is there a reason you're using round braces instead of letting your commands live free in `do ... done`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your loop in a subshell due to the parentheses in `do ( ... ) done`.  Each iteration gets its own subshell.

You want to use `TimeVec` in the parent shell, but the children processes cannot modify a variable in their parent process, and they cannot share the variable among them.  So the variable is always null to begin with as seen by each iteration.